# Is there a serious TV channel which is for Buddhist community?

Tags: media

I watch TV. As a Buddhist which TV channels should I watch?

Comment: which country are you from?

Comment: @GeethW I am not seeking geographically bound Channel.

Comment: good question! there's countless Christian ones...

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of any TV channels which are not geographically bound, I think you can use YouTube channels, that have regularly published content, as sort of TV channels.

Here are some Theravada Buddhist YouTube channels with content in English:

- [Buddhist Society of Western Australia](https://www.youtube.com/c/BuddhistSocietyWA/featured)
- [Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu](https://www.youtube.com/c/yuttadhammo/featured)
- [Abhayagiri Buddhist Monastery](https://www.youtube.com/c/AbhayagiriBuddhistMonastery/featured)
- [Ajahn Sona](https://www.youtube.com/c/AjahnSona/featured)
- [Vimutti Buddhist Monastery](https://www.youtube.com/user/VimuttiMonastery/featured)

Here are some Tibetan Buddhist YouTube channels with content in English:

- [Dalai Lama](https://www.youtube.com/dalailama/featured)
- [Yongey Mingyur Rinpoche](https://www.youtube.com/user/MingyurRinpoche/featured)
- [Sakyong Mipham Rinpoche](https://www.youtube.com/c/SakyongMiphamRinpoche/featured)
- [Bodhicharya Dharma Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/BodhicharyaDharmaChannel/featured)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/ -
While this is not TV, it's a huge collection of Buddhist audio tracks / podcasts: